# ORDER BY CASE WHEN can't be used on an COUNT() AS Foo result column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a query in which I am trying to allow sorting based on a parameter passed in by a C# SQL Server client library. My query currently looks like this ...

```
SELECT d.OpinionDocumentId,
       d.DisplayTitle, 
       d.Court,
       d.State,
       d.Date,
       (SELECT i.Identifier + ', '
        FROM dbo.OpinionDocumentCitationIdentifiers i
        WHERE i.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId = b.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId
        FOR XML PATH('')) AS Identifiers,
       COUNT(DISTINCT c.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId1) AS CitationCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT t.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId) AS CitedByCount

FROM dbo.OpinionDocumentBookmarks b

INNER JOIN dbo.OpinionDocuments d ON d.OpinionDocumentId = b.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId
LEFT JOIN dbo.OpinionDocumentOpinionDocuments c ON c.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId = b.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId
LEFT JOIN dbo.OpinionDocumentOpinionDocuments t ON t.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId1 = b.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId

WHERE b.Account_AccountId = @accountId

GROUP BY b.OpinionDocumentBookmarkId,
       b.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId,
       d.OpinionDocumentId,
       d.DisplayTitle,
       d.Court,
       d.State,
       d.Date

ORDER BY CASE WHEN @sort = 'DisplayTitle' THEN d.DisplayTitle END,
       CASE WHEN @sort = 'Date' THEN d.Date END,
       CASE WHEN @sort = 'Court' THEN d.Court END,
       CASE WHEN @sort = 'State' THEN d.State END,
       CASE WHEN @sort = 'Citations' THEN CitationCount END

OFFSET @skip ROWS FETCH NEXT @take ROWS ONLY
```

As you can see, I'm trying to allow sorting based on a parameter. I'm trying to allow sorting on the aggregated `CitationCount` or `CitedByCount` columns. I can sort by these columns when I do not use the `ORDER BY CASE WHEN`, but when I try to specify that as a column in the `ORDER BY CASE WHEN` I get an error saying that it's not a column.

Is this possible?

Comment: change the `THEN CitationCount` with `THEN COUNT(DISTINCT t.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId)`

Comment: oh nice that works. if you want to post that as an answer, I can mark it as solution.

Comment: It is not necessary to dump your entire train wreck of a query into the question to illustrate the issue. Please edit it down to the smallest query you can think of that shows the problem - see [SSCCE](http://sscce.ofg)

Comment: Fascinating.  The SQL Server docs say "A sort column can be specified as a name or column alias," consistent with my general understanding of SQL, so I would have expected the original `GROUP BY` clause to work.  I guess the difference is that you are sorting by an expression, but it's not obvious why a column alias cannot be used in that expression.  Anyway, I'm glad it's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        d.OpinionDocumentId
        , d.DisplayTitle
        , d.Court
        , d.[State]
        , d.[Date]
        , (
            SELECT i.Identifier + ', '
            FROM dbo.OpinionDocumentCitationIdentifiers AS i
            WHERE i.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId = b.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) AS Identifiers
        , COUNT(DISTINCT c.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId1) AS CitationCount
        , COUNT(DISTINCT t.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId) AS CitedByCount
    FROM
        dbo.OpinionDocumentBookmarks AS b
        INNER JOIN dbo.OpinionDocuments AS d
            ON d.OpinionDocumentId = b.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.OpinionDocumentOpinionDocuments AS c
            ON c.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId = b.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.OpinionDocumentOpinionDocuments AS t
            ON t.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId1 = b.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId
    WHERE b.Account_AccountId = @accountId
    GROUP BY
        b.OpinionDocumentBookmarkId
        , b.OpinionDocument_OpinionDocumentId
        , d.OpinionDocumentId
        , d.DisplayTitle
        , d.Court
        , d.State
        , d.Dat
    ) AS H
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @sort = 'DisplayTitle' THEN DisplayTitle END,
    CASE WHEN @sort = 'Date' THEN [Date] END,
    CASE WHEN @sort = 'Court' THEN Court END,
    CASE WHEN @sort = 'State' THEN [State] END,
    CASE WHEN @sort = 'Citations' THEN CitationCount END
```